# "quite an institution" meaning?

Tags: meaning, idioms

What does "quite an institution" mean? Here is an example:

> As many of you know, the Capitol just celebrated our 85th anniversary
>   in December of last year– we’re quite an institution around here! But
>   while we value our historic standing, we are constantly striving for
>   ways to expand our services to better serve the community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Quite a/an" is used to show that something is of an unusually noticeable or remarkable kind:

> She is quite a girl = She is a remarkable girl
>
> It was quite a walk = The walk was very enjoyable/interesting...

You can look up other examples in some dictionaries, for example [here](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=quite%20a), or [here](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/quite).

Comment: _Quite a walk_ can also mean it was long :) But your explanation is good :)

Comment: Sure it can, hence the ellipsis in the example :) All we know from this short example is that the walk was quite remarkable. Distance is often the cause :)

Answer (score 3):

"Quite an X" is an idiom meaning a very extreme or unusual example of X, usually in a positive way, but depending on context it could be bad. Like if you say, "Wow, that's quite a car!" you mean that it is a very good car. That might mean very fast, very luxurious, etc, depending on the context.

If someone says, "That's quite a problem you have there," that would be a bad thing. It is a very serious or perhaps unusual problem.

"We're quite an institution" means that the institution they're referring to is a very good and great institution. From the context you give above I think they are stressing the longevity of the capitol building, though a larger context might indicate that they're talking about some group that is organizing the celebration.

Comment: I think this depends on the speaker.  For example, used sarcastically to complain about poor service at a restaurant or something.

Comment: @MAW74656 Well, sure. The meaning of any word can be essentially reversed by saying it sarcastically. "Oh, Fred is SUCH an HONEST man."